# How to validate both input text

Tags: javascript, html, forms

`I want to show the message "Input Number Only" if I oninput the alphabet.` The first text box is successfully show but when I input alphabet into the second text box it does not show anything at the span. How to edit my code so that it will show the message after I on input the alphabet. Here my code :

```js
function allvalidate(){
    var inp = document.getElementsByClassName('text');
    for(var i in inp){
    if(inp[i].type == "text"){
        if(!/^\d{1,}$/.test(inp[i].value)){
            error.textContent = "Input Number Only";
            error.style.color = "red";

            return false;
            }
        else {
            error.textContent = "";
            }
        return true;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<p>Number of Customer</p>
                <p><input type="text" name="people" class="text" placeholder="no.of people" size="18" maxlength="10" oninput="allvalidate()"></p>
                <p>Age</p>
                <p><input type="text" name="post" class="text" placeholder="postcode" size="18" maxlength="2" oninput="allvalidate()"></p>
                <span id="error"></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the following statement:

```
for(var i in inp){
```

with

```
for(let i=0 ;i<inp.length;i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

A `delegated event listener` bound to the document can intercept and process all the input elements without needing to explicitly add the `oninput` event handler to each one as above. That event handler can likely also be simplified by using `isNaN` rather than a regex

```js
const errspan=document.getElementById('error');

document.addEventListener('input',e=>{
  errspan.textContent = "";  
  if( e.target.type=='text' && isNaN( e.target.value ) ) {
    errspan.textContent = "Input Number Only";
  }
})
```

```css
#error{
  color:red
}
```

```html
<p>Number of Customer</p>
<p>
  <input type="text" name="people" class="text" placeholder="no.of people" size="18" maxlength="10" />
</p>

<p>Age</p>
<p>
  <input type="text" name="post" class="text" placeholder="postcode" size="18" maxlength="2" />
</p>


<span id="error"></span>
```